# Highcharts: How to rename series

Tags: javascript, rename, highcharts, series

I'm using highcharts in my web application and I was wondering if there's any way to rename a series after the chart hast been created??

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no method for doing this in the API. You could remove the series and add it again with another name, but that will make the animations run a second time and I think it will be colored with a new color as well.

Comment: Thanks, works pretty well, making the animations run a second time actually looks good, if you take the default settings the color will change, yes, but since you can set the color yourself it's not a problem, either.

Answer (score 53):

actually, there's a way now. In highchars 3.0 series added a new api, called update:

```
chart.series[0].update({name:"name u want to change"}, false);
chart.redraw();
```

it will not only update the series name below the chart, but the name in tooltip as well.

Cheers!

Comment: This method works and is recommended over the eolsson's accepted answer.

Comment: Seems like adding the false flag doesnt do much though. I took it out and no longer had to call chart.redraw()

Comment: According to the documentation provided by [Highcharts](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update), the last flag is provided to indicate whether redraw or not the chart.

Answer (score 8):

This seems to  work :

```
chart.series[1].name="Renamed";
chart.redraw();
```

Answer (score -1):

It is not required to Redraw chart again
We can include it along with the series option in the Chart declaration as below:

```
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'high_container'
        },title: {
            text: 'IO Signal  Data'
        },subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: GPS Modem'
        },

        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Value'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle'
        },


        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            labels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function () { return ddd[this.value][0]; }, //<=== the value to plot chart

            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: ddd,
            name: SeriesName
        }]
    });
```

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, but the question was about how to *rename* a series, not how to set its name when instantiating the chart. Also, most of the code in the example is irrelevant anyway.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following to change the series name:

```js
$(chart.series[0].legendItem.element).children('tspan').text('newLabelName');
```